How do I record videos with WinAPI for my console Emulator?
I have made a Nintendo Emulator and I want to record videos of what the player is playing. I know about FFmpeg, but I don't know how to set up it/use it. All I need is a .lib file that let me throw it frames and it outputs as a video file.
I'm kinda lost, the emulator is done using Allegro 5, so it is for Windows and Linux.
Allegro doesn't have facilities for recording videos. I have to make it with winapi features.
Any suggestion of what I have to do?

Are the frames in RGB format? Can you run FFmpeg as a process from your coding language? Meaning that... Is using standard in/out a possible option for you? Find out, because FFmpeg will accept RGB frames sent through std in/out and write an output video file.

PS: Not clear what video format you want to save as here, but see if there is a c/c++ encoder for your required format-X. For example use libVPX for data to put inside webM or use OpenH264 for data to put inside MP4. Stick with finding a way to encode H264/MP4 if not sure what format to pursue.
